# Is there a numpy alternative to this for loop problem?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 3 arrays of the same length:

```
import numpy as np

weights = np.array([10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40])
resistances = np.array([15, 16.5, 18, 19.5, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39])
depths = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

I want to take each item in `weights`, then find the nearest match that is >= this item in `resistances`, and then using the index of this nearest match I want to return the corresponding value from `depths` i.e. `depths[index]`.

BUT, with the additional condition that if nothing is >= the max value in `weights` then just return last value in `depths`. I then want to populate a list with the results.

Is there a better way than the for loop approach below? I would like to avoid the loop.

```
SWP = []
for w in weights:
    if len(depths[w<=resistances]) == 0:
        swp=depths[-1]
    else:
        swp = np.min(depths[w<=resistances])
    SWP.append(swp)
SWP
```

Comment: The provided implementation doesn't match the explanation (*find the nearest match that is >= this item in resistances*). For example *weights[3] -> 22* the output should be 5 (index 5 of resistances is 24) but is 4 (index 4 is 21, which is less than 22).

Comment: I believe you're looking for [np.searchsorted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html).

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny you're right, I've corrected the code.

Comment: @VladimirFokow I've updated the text and code to address that.

Comment: @QuangHoang ```depths[np.searchsorted(resistances,weights)]``` is a very good one line solution except does not deal with the edge case w=40 which gives position 11 but depth[11] is out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`.clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.clip.html)
the indices that `np.searchsorted` produces with `len(resistances)-1`:

```py
depths[
    np.searchsorted(resistances, weights).clip(max=len(resistances)-1)
]
```

So any index larger than the last one - will become the last one.

---

Alternative idea (but only if your `resistances` are sorted) - clip the `weights` with the maximum of  `resistances`:

```py
depths[
    np.searchsorted(resistances, weights.clip(max=resistances.max()))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually to do what you're talking about you want to create a function that can be mapped over a list.

```py
import numpy as np

weights = np.array([10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40])
resistances = np.array([15, 16.5, 18, 19.5, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39])
depth = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

def evaluate_weight(w):
    depths = depth[resistances<=w]
    return np.max(depths) if len(depths) else 0

SWP = list(map(evaluate_weight, weights))
```

Comment: If general concurrence is that mapping is the best way to do this, then I will accept this answer. Will give a bit longer for other suggestions first.